# sql table optimization: primary and secondary indexes

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Do people usually make every column in a table a secondary index to be on the safe side in case the customer decides to use either field to search for a record?

Does the search first go through the secondary indexes and then to the primary key? Thus narrowing down to the requested data?

What is the point of having secondary index if you already have a column that is a primary key?

Comment: Your question appears to be about indexes and not keys. That is how others have also interpreted it and I've now edited the question accordingly. Please undo my edit and clarify your question if you actually meant to ask about keys because that would be a significantly different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you only index columns that need to be.  Adding additional indexes would normally be considered premature optimization.

Most optimizers will identify the fastest method to find the least number of records.  This may be to use and index, but may be a full table scan.  If there are multiple indexes that can be used, often only one is used, and the resulting records compared against the remaining criteria.  If multiple indexes are used, then the resulting result sets need to be matched, and records which weren't found in both indexes eliminated.

It is common to use surrogate keys for tables where the natural key is subject to change, or very (purposely vague) long.  The natural key in this case would be indexed as a secondary unique key. In some cases there may be competing natural keys, in which case all the natural keys would have unique indexes.

Answer (score 4):

(The following response applies to Sql Server.  Some parts may vary for other DBMSs.)

Last question first: "What is the point of having secondary keys if you already have a column that is a primary key?"  I illustrate with the example of a table `"People (Id int primary key, firstname varchar(40), middlename varchar(40), lastname varchar(40))".`  Now consider the query `"select * from people where lastname = 'flynn'".` If there is no index on the lastname column, the table will be scanned sequentially to find matches.  Every row must be accessed.  The primary key index does not help at all here. If you index the lastname column, the result can be found much more quickly.

You would normally index only those columns that would be useful to the queries your application issues.  If your queries never have a join or where condition on a column named "MiddleName" then no benefit would come from indexing that column.  You don't want to add unnecessary indexes because they increase the cost of data inserts and updates that involve that column.

We usually say that Sql Server uses only a single index per table instance in a query.  So a query like "select * from people where firstname='Elroy' and lastname = 'Flynn' " would use at most one index, even if both firstname and lastname have indexes. Sql Server would choose one or the other index based on the statistics it has collected from the data values.

In full completeness, I have to get a little advanced here, and discuss clustered vs. non-clustered indexes.  A table can have only one clustered index: the rest are non-clustered.  The previous paragraph notwithstanding, when a non-clustered index is used for to resolve a query, the index lookup produces an intermediate result which is the full value of the key associated with whichever index is the clustered index (often, the primary key). That is, the leaves of every non-clustered index contain the clustered key value, not a row pointer. After finding this clustered key, the clustered index is then used to resolve the lookup to a specific database row.  So, ultimately, ALL index lookups eventually use the clustered index.

Still, for practical purposes, it is usually adequate and simpler to say that only a single index is used per table instance. Note that if a table is aliased in a query so that it appears more than once, a different index could be used for the different references.  e.g., "`select * from people p1 join people p2 on p1.firstname = p2.lastname"` could use a firstname index on the p1 instance and a lastname index on the p2 instance.

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131(v=SQL.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

One other item not mentioned yet, every additional index has to be maintained.  So if you have indexes covering all your columns in several different combinations, not only will they take up lots of space, every update/insert/delete has the potential to change one or more of those indexes.  This will result in those operations being slowed way down in many situations.

It's always a tradeoff.  The more indexes you have the more work the server has to do to keep them up to date, but the more likely it is that you'll have at least one that will cover any query you throw at that table.

Answer (score 0):

"On the safe side"?  No.

An index trades space and insert-time for select-time.  Unnecessary keys chew up disk-space and slow inserts in return for speeding up a query that never occurs.

As with all optimizations, do query optimizations *last* -- build the system then observe its behavior.

The primary/secondary distinction in a highly technical one.  All indices exist to speed up queries and/or enforce certain integrity constraints.